# Combining BERT word embeddings vectors to retain combined meaning

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model

I am looking for ways to handle the context of conversation in an "organic" way with usage of BERT class models.

Is it possible to somehow combine many BERT base word embedding vectors generated out of different textual inputs to provide single word embedding retaining the combined meaning of those many separate vectors?

I am using BERT base model to generate word embeddings vector for the phrase "buy", and I end up with certain word embeddings vector.

At the next step I do the same but for different phrase which is "apple" which gives me vector of same dimensions yet different values.

Is it possible to somehow process these two vectors together that the resulting, single vector would retain the meaning (in scope of model's knowledge representation) of both vectors?

For instance, so it would be similar (in terms of cosine similarity between 2 vectors) to the vector generated out of the phrase "buy apple".

I've found several papers regarding the matter of conversation context handling and some of them did mention making use of global state which would modify the model's outputs.
Other papers mention applying additional layers to the output that would be capable of retaining some memory.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

What is your main goal with combining the vectors in this case?
As I understand it, you want for example apple [0001] combined with buy [0100] to become a new vector that represents 'buy apple' with the goal to handle context in an organic way?

With the idea that you propose, you would not be able to have any organic meaning representations because the vectors for the words remain the same in every context. This is the case with more traditional static word embedding models that were omnipresent before the introduction of transformer based word embedding models.

With contextual word embedding models like BERT, the model 'learns' the meaning of a word in every context and gives it a vector within the model that represents that specific occurance of a word. So buy in 'buy now!' (imperative) gets a different vector than buy in 'I buy my apples on the market' (present form).

As I understand from your question, it seems like you are thinking to complex - BERT is a great model that can handle context already! There is no need to 'stack' these embeddings to create prhase embeddings for context.

Please try to explain a bit more in detail what you would like to achieve and maybe link a paper that describes this if this is not the answer you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for your response. To clarify my point, I would like to somehow maintain context of whole, multi-turn conversation - basically a dialogue system.  In my example, these two phrases are two separate model inference attempts occurring in separate spans of time.
Here are some examples that could maybe somehow extend on what I'm having on my mind:
- https://arxiv.org/pdf/2104.06529.pdf
- https://mccormickml.com/2021/06/29/combining-categorical-numerical-features-with-bert/#s3-bert-with-all-features

Comment: @coso Ah I see what you mean now! I'm afraid I cannot help you with that, it's also a bit beyond my knowledge. Good luck!